# is there a difference from a css point of view between

Tags: html, css

```
<div> 
  <form> 
  </form> 
</div>
```

and..

```
<form> 
 <div> 
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out here? I'm trying to read between the lines, but I just can't see where you're going with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can change inheritance, perceived width, and the selectors you use. So, yes, there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact to select children one is `div > form` and the other is `form > div` no.